# MAGENTO 1.9 Soap delete all image from product

Tags: magento-1.9, image, soap, media, web-services

I'm using the SOAP web service to add images to products after I import them. Now before I want to add the image to the specific product, I want to delete all the images of that product. But the SOAP service wants me to specify the name of the image. This is randomly generated so I don't have the name of the image for each product.

Ho do I delete all the images of 1 product with a SOAP call.

Here's a part of the code:

```
foreach ($array as $prod) {
            $sku = $prod[0];

            $photo = $prod[8];
            $data = file_get_contents($photo);
            $base64 = base64_encode($data);

            $file = array(
                'content' => $base64,
                'mime' => 'image/jpeg'
            );

            $resultDelete = $client->catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove($sessionId,(string)$sku, '');
            $result = $client->catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate($sessionId, (string)$sku, array('file' => $file, 'label' => $sku, 'position' => '1', 'types' => array('thumbnail', 'image', 'small_image')), '', 'sku');

            print_r($resultDelete . ' - ' . $result . '<br>');

        }
```

As you can see, what do I need to add to the parameters of

catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove

to make it delete all the images of that product instead of one?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by first getting all the image file name of the current product, and deleting them. Not optimal but it works.

```
foreach ($array as $prod) {
            $sku = $prod[0];

            $currentImages = $client->catalogProductAttributeMediaList($sessionId, $sku);

            foreach($currentImages as $img)
            {
                $file = $img->file;
                $client->catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove($sessionId,(string)$sku, (string)$file);
            }

            $photo = $prod[8];
            $data = file_get_contents($photo);
            $base64 = base64_encode($data);

            $file = array(
                'content' => $base64,
                'mime' => 'image/jpeg'
            );

            $result = $client->catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate($sessionId, (string)$sku, array('file' => $file, 'label' => $sku, 'position' => '1', 'types' => array('thumbnail', 'image', 'small_image')), '', 'sku');

            print_r($result . '<br>');
        }
```